# Inherit class with child class as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is it possible to inherit a class with the child class as template argument?

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
  T t;
};

struct B:A<B>{
  unsigned u;
};

int main(){
  B b;
}
```

Comment: It's the child class here that's given as template argument. And yes it's possible. Just not a member of `T t;` in the base class. Check out the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to see what it's useful for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

Your problem seems to be the error `‘A<T>::t’ has incomplete type`. See for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/10931/).

If you

1. declare B before A and
2. use a pointer in the structure A, it works well.

---

```
struct B;
template<typename T>
struct A{
    T *t;
};
struct B : A<B>{
    unsigned u;
};
int main(){
    B b;
}
```

Comment: Well, instinctively I declared B before A, but this is optional. Only point 2 is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

```
Template <class T>
struct A {};

struct B : public A<B> {};
```

It wouldn't work with containers very well. See "Programming Principles and Practice 2nd Edition" by Stroustrup 19.2.4 p686.

Comment: This compiles fine in your example; but add a reference to type `T` in your `struct A` and it fails to compile because the compiler doesn't know about type `B` at the template instantiation point in the code (similar to a `#def`) .. so while you're example is correct, it fails to take into account scope of definition and how that affects templates.

Answer (score 0):

you can,but in your case above it can not,you can not use it as a nonstatic  data member.

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
  static T t;
};
template<typename T>
T A<T>::t=T();

struct B:A<B>{
  unsigned u;
};

int main(){
  B b;
}
```

Comment: A static data member of `T` would be pretty useless though.